# Question about inclusion map

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $A$ be a ring and $A/I$ a quotient ring where $I$ is a ideal of $A$.

My teacher said that if there's an injective homomorphism $\varphi:A\to A/I$, $x\mapsto \overline{x}$ (an inclusion map), then I can consider $x$ and $\varphi(x)=\overline{x} $ as equal elements. That is, if I'm working with the equation $y+x=z$, with $y,z\in A$, then I can, if it's convenient, swap $x$ by $\overline{x}$ and get $y+\overline{x}=z$.

I would like to confirm if this is really true since it is strange to consider an element $x$ equal to its equivalence class $\overline{x}$, for example.

I wonder if this is the same thing as considering $1=\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$ although $1$ and $\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$ are quite different expressions.

My question is: can I really, if I get an inclusive map $\sigma:A\to B,\, x\mapsto \sigma(x)$, consider $x$ equals to $\sigma(x)$?

**EDIT**: Let $K$ be a field. Change the map $\varphi:A\to A/I,\, x\mapsto \overline{x}$ by the map $\varphi' :K\to K[X],\, a\mapsto a(X)$ in which $a(X)=a$ is the constant polynomial of $K[X]$ equal to $a$. Note that $\varphi'$ is a injective homomorfism.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the correct tags for this question. I **believe** I put the right ones.

Comment: The point is that in this case $A$ and $A/I$ are isomorphic, which means that $I=0$

Comment: I think @leibnewtz is correct. If $I\ne 0,$ then $\varphi$ is **never** injective.

Comment: My example was not good. If the contradomain were another set such that the map was not surjective, would it make sense to say that those elements are the same? My teacher used this in another example which I decided not to put because it is part of a specific context which I can not reproduce here.

Comment: @leibnewtz please see my **EDIT** in the question which is closest to the map my teacher used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an inclusion map $A \to B$, you can consider $A$ to be a substructure of $B$. In that sense, yes, you can consider elements of $A$ to be elements of $B$. This is true for any algebraic structure, not only rings.

Be careful though: the names you used for elements of $A$ a priori will not necessarily be the same names they have in $B$. For a simple example, there is a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by multiplication by $2$. It's injective, so it should follow your rule. But it makes sense to view it as inclusion only if we name the elements of the domain $\{0,2,4,\dots\}$ instead of $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.